# In R: extract number (dosage) from text string into a new variable

Tags: r, regex, gsub

recently I have started learning R in order to analyze data. I have a certain (CSV) datafile, which I have successfully imported in R. This dataset contain several variables (columns), one of which is string containing text and numbers. I would like to extract a certain number (being dosages) from this string into a new variable (column).

**The variable source variable contains entries in the following formats**

```
source <- c(
  "NIFEDI SDZ RET 30MG TAB MGA", 
  "HYDROCHL THIAZ PCH 12,5MG T",
  "METOPROL SU SDZ RET 200 TAB"
)
```

**What I would like to create is a variable (column) called 'dosages' that only contains a number**

```
dosages <- c('30', '12,5', '200')
```

So in short. There is one variable containing several different formats from which I want to extract the number into a new variable (column) in the same row.

Should I do this using Gsub, RegEx or some other function I havent learned about?
I have tried using the search function and found rather similar questions, but none that fully answered mine. I am new to stackoverflow though, so my apologies if this have been answered and I did not look propperly..

Comment: Can you please proved an subset of the data, and the code you have already tried?

Comment: Thanks for your message, sorry I hadn't replied earlier. I took a few days off because of  Easter. Will do when Ill get into the office tomorrow.

Comment: The answer given by James Curran helped me, should I still post my part of the code now it has been mostly replaced by his?

Answer (score 2):

```
Lines = c("NIFEDI SDZ RET 30MG TAB MGA",
  "HYDROCHL THIAZ PCH 12,5MG T",
  "METOPROL SU SDZ RET 200 TAB")

gsub("[^0-9]+([0-9]+(,[0-9])?)(MG)?.*$", "\\1", Lines)
```

```
> gsub("[^0-9]+([0-9]+(,[0-9])?)(MG)?.*$", "\\1", Lines)
[1] "30"   "12,5" "200"
```

Of course they're still strings at this point. You can coerce them into numbers, with `as.numeric` but you'll need to do something about the commas.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will try to implement your lines into my code tomorrow when I get into the office. Will report back

Comment: I incorporated the above line into my code and it worked. But better yet, I have better understanding how to use Gsub. Thanks a lot!